# Visual Composer Parallax for Video Backgrounds

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html5-video, visual-composer

I already broke my head trying to find the right solution. I added new row in my Visual Composer and now I just want to add a parallax effect to it background.

The parallax effect CSS is:

```
{background-position: center!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
    background-attachment: fixed!important;
    background-size: cover!important;}
```

([Here is an example](https://codepen.io/nikkz/pen/qZJKqG).)

I'm trying to edit this part

```
<div class="video-wrap">
                                           <div id="video-wrap">
                                        <video "id"="my-video" "class="video" width="1920" height="800" poster="'.$v_image.'" preload="metadata" loop autoplay muted>';
                                                if(!empty($video_webm)) { $output .= '


                                                <source type="video/webm" src="'.$video_webm.'">'; }
                                                if(!empty($video_mp4)) { $output .= '<source type="video/mp4" src="'.$video_mp4.'">'; }
                                                if(!empty($video_ogv)) { $output .= '<source type="video/ogg" src="'. $video_ogv.'">'; }
                                             $output .='<object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/js/flashmediaelement.swf">
                                                        <param name="movie" value="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/js/flashmediaelement.swf" />
                                                        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file='.$video_mp4.'" />
                                                        <img src="'.$v_image.'" width="1920" height="800" title="No video playback capabilities" alt="Video thumb" />
                                                </object>
                                        </video>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                </section>';
```

of code, but all in vain

```
<?php
$output = $el_class = $css = $el_id = $after_wrapper_open = $before_wrapper_close = '';
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'el_class' => '',
    'row_type' => 'row',
    'use_as_box' => '',
    'use_row_as_full_screen_section' => '',
    'type' => 'full_width',
    'expandable_content_top_padding'=>'',
    'header_style' => '',
    'parallax_content_width' => 'in_grid',
    'anchor' => '',
    'in_content_menu'=>'',
    'content_menu_title' => '',
    'content_menu_icon' => '',
    'angled_section' => '',
    'angled_section_direction' => '',
    'angled_section_position' => 'both',
    'video' => '',
    'video_overlay' => '',
    'video_overlay_image' => '',
    'video_webm' => '',
    'video_mp4' => '',
    'video_ogv' => '',
    'video_image' => '',
    'background_color' => '',
    'full_screen_section_height' => 'no',
    'vertically_align_content_in_middle' => 'no',
    'section_height' => '',
    'parallax_speed' => '1',
    'background_image' => '',
    'background_image_as_pattern' => 'without_pattern',
    'border_color' => '',
    'padding_top' => '',
    'padding_bottom' => '',
    'side_padding' => '',
    'row_negative_margin' => '',
    'parallax_side_padding' => '',
    'text_align' => is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left',
    'more_button_label' =>'More Facts',
    'less_button_label'=>'Less Facts',
    'button_position'=>'center',
    'color'=>'',
    'hover_color'=>'',
    'content_background_color' => '',
    'css_animation'=>'',
    'transition_delay'=>'',
    'css' => '',
    'el_id' => ''
), $atts));

//wp_enqueue_style( 'js_composer_front' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpb_composer_front_js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'backgroundVideo' );
//wp_enqueue_style('js_composer_custom_css');

$el_class = $this->getExtraClass($el_class);

$css_class = apply_filters( VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, 'vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid '. ( $this->settings('base')==='vc_row_inner' ? 'vc_inner ' : '' ) . $el_class . vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css, ' ' ), $this->settings['base'], $atts );

if($type == "grid"){
    $css_class_type =  " grid_section";
} else {
    $css_class_type =  "";
}

if($type == "grid"){
    $css_class_type_inner =  " section_inner";
} else {
    $css_class_type_inner =  " full_section_inner";
}

$header_style_data = '';
if($header_style != ""){
    $header_style_data =  'data-q_header_style="'.$header_style.'"';
}

$css_class_video =  "";
if($video == "show_video"){
    $css_class_video =  " video_section";
}

$css_class_in_content_menu =  "";
if($in_content_menu == "in_content_menu"){
    $css_class_in_content_menu =  " in_content_menu";
}

$_image ="";
if($background_image != '' || $background_image != ' ') { 
    $_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $background_image, 'full');
}

$overlay_image ="";
if($video_overlay_image != '' && $video_overlay_image != ' ') { 
    $overlay_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $video_overlay_image, 'full');
}

if($css_animation != ""){
    $clsss_css_animation =  "  " . $css_animation;
} else {
    $clsss_css_animation =  "";
}
$delay = "";
if($transition_delay != ""){
    $delay = " style='transition-delay:" . $transition_delay . "ms; -webkit-animation-delay:" . $transition_delay . "ms; animation-delay:" . $transition_delay . "ms;'";
}
$anchor_id = "";
if($anchor != ""){
    $anchor_id = ' data-q_id="#'.$anchor.'"';
}

$menu_title = "";
if($content_menu_title != ""){
    $menu_title = ' data-q_title="'.$content_menu_title.'"';
}

$menu_icon = "";
if($content_menu_icon != ""){
    $menu_icon = ' data-q_icon="'.$content_menu_icon.'"';
}

$use_row_as_box_class="";
if($use_as_box == 'use_row_as_box'){
    $use_row_as_box_class = ' use_row_as_box';
}

$row_negative_margin_class="";
if($row_negative_margin == 'disable_negative_margin'){
    $row_negative_margin_class = ' disable_negative_margin';
}

$full_screen_section_class = "";
if($use_row_as_full_screen_section == "yes"){
    $full_screen_section_class = " full_screen_section";
}

if($angled_section == 'yes') {

    if($background_color != ""){
        $angled_section_style = 'style="fill:'.$background_color.';"';
    }
    else
        $angled_section_style = "";
}

$parallax_section_classes = '';
if($full_screen_section_height == 'yes'){
    $parallax_section_classes .=  ' qode_full_screen_height_parallax';

    if($vertically_align_content_in_middle == 'yes'){
        $parallax_section_classes .= ' qode_vertical_middle_align';

        $after_wrapper_open .= '<div class="parallax_content_outer">';
        $before_wrapper_close .= '</div>';
    }

}

$row_id = '';
if($el_id !== '') {
    $row_id = 'id="'.esc_attr($el_id).'"';
}

if($row_type == 'row') {
    $output .= '<div '.$row_id.' '.$anchor_id.' '.$menu_title.' '.$menu_icon.' '.$header_style_data.' class="' . $css_class . $css_class_type . $css_class_in_content_menu . $css_class_video . $use_row_as_box_class . $row_negative_margin_class  . $full_screen_section_class .'"';
    if($background_color != "" || $border_color != "" || $padding_top != "" || $padding_bottom != "" || $text_align != "" || $_image != ""){
            $output .= " style='";
                if($background_color != ""){
                    $output .="background-color:".$background_color.";";
                }
                if($_image != ""){
                    if($background_image_as_pattern != "without_pattern") {
                        $output .="background: url(".$_image[0].");";
                        $output .="background-repeat: repeat;";
                        $output .="background-position: 0 0;";
                        $output .="background-size: inherit;";
                    } else {
                        $output .="background:url(".$_image[0].");";
                    }
                }
                if($border_color != ""){
                    if($use_as_box == 'use_row_as_box') {
                        $output .=" border: 1px solid ".$border_color.";";
                    }else {
                        $output .=" border-bottom: 1px solid ".$border_color.";";
                    }
                }
                if($padding_top != ""){
                    $output .=" padding-top:".$padding_top."px;";
                }
                if($padding_bottom != ""){
                    $output .=" padding-bottom:".$padding_bottom."px;";
                }
                $output .= ' text-align:' . $text_align . ';';
                $output.="'";
        }
    $output.=">";

    if($angled_section == 'yes' && $angled_section_position != 'bottom') {
        $output .= '<svg class="angled-section svg-top" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 86 86" width="100%" height="86">';
        if($angled_section_direction == 'from_left_to_right'){
            $output .= '<polygon points="0,0 0,86 86,86" ' . $angled_section_style . ' />';
        }
        if($angled_section_direction == 'from_right_to_left'){
            $output .= '<polygon points="0,86 86,0 86,86" ' . $angled_section_style . ' />';
        }
        $output .= '</svg>';
    }

    if($video == "show_video"){
        $v_image = wp_get_attachment_url($video_image);
        $v_overlay_image = wp_get_attachment_url($video_overlay_image);

        if($use_row_as_full_screen_section == "yes"){
            $output .= '<div class="video-overlay';
                            if($video_overlay == "show_video_overlay"){
                                $output .= ' active';
                            }
                            $output .= '"';
                            $output .= ($overlay_image !== '' && $overlay_image !== ' ') ? " style='background:url(" . $overlay_image[0] . ");background-position: center!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
    background-attachment: fixed!important;
    background-size: cover!important;'" : '';
                            $output .= '></div><div id="paralun" class="video-wrap">';
            $output .= '<video class="full_screen_sections_video" width="1920" height="800" poster="'.$v_image.'" controls="controls" preload="auto" loop autoplay muted>';
                            if(!empty($video_webm)) { $output .= '<source type="video/webm" src="'.$video_webm.'">'; }
                            if(!empty($video_mp4)) { $output .= '<source type="video/mp4" src="'.$video_mp4.'">'; }
                            if(!empty($video_ogv)) { $output .= '<source type="video/ogg" src="'. $video_ogv.'">'; }
                            $output .='<object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/js/flashmediaelement.swf">
                                        <param name="movie" value="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/js/flashmediaelement.swf" />
                                        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file='.$video_mp4.'" />
                                        <img src="'.$v_image.'" width="1920" height="800" title="No video playback capabilities" alt="Video thumb" />
                                </object>
                        </video>
                        </div>';
        } else {

            $output .= '<div class="mobile-video-image" style="background: url('.$v_image.')"></div><div class="video-overlay';
                                if($video_overlay == "show_video_overlay"){
                                    $output .= ' active';
                                }
                                $output .= '"';
                                $output .= ($overlay_image !== '' && $overlay_image !== ' ') ? " style='background:url(" . $overlay_image[0] . ");'" : '';
                                $output .= '></div>**<div class="video-wrap">
                                       <div id="video-wrap">
                                    <video "id"="my-video" "class="video" width="1920" height="800" poster="'.$v_image.'" preload="metadata" loop autoplay muted>';
                                            if(!empty($video_webm)) { $output .= '


                                            <source type="video/webm" src="'.$video_webm.'">'; }
                                            if(!empty($video_mp4)) { $output .= '<source type="video/mp4" src="'.$video_mp4.'">'; }
                                            if(!empty($video_ogv)) { $output .= '<source type="video/ogg" src="'. $video_ogv.'">'; }
                                         $output .='<object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/js/flashmediaelement.swf">
                                                    <param name="movie" value="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/js/flashmediaelement.swf" />
                                                    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file='.$video_mp4.'" />
                                                    <img src="'.$v_image.'" width="1920" height="800" title="No video playback capabilities" alt="Video thumb" />
                                            </object>
                                    </video>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            </section>';**
        }                   
    }
    $output .= '<div class="' . $css_class_type_inner . ' clearfix"';
    if($side_padding != ""){
            $output .= " style='padding: 0% ".$side_padding."%'";
        }
    $output .= '>';
    if($type == "grid"){
        $output .= "<div class='section_inner_margin clearfix'>";
    }
    if($row_type == "row" && $css_animation != ""){
        $output .= '<div class="'. $clsss_css_animation .'"><div'. $delay .'>';
    }
}else if($row_type == 'parallax'){
    $output .='<section '.$row_id.' '.$anchor_id.' '.$menu_title.' '.$menu_icon.' '.$header_style_data.' data-speed="'. $parallax_speed .'" class="parallax_section_holder '.$el_class.' '.$parallax_section_classes.$css_class_in_content_menu.'" style = "';
    $output .= ($section_height !='' || $section_height!=' ') ? ' height:' . $section_height . 'px;' : '';
    $output .= ($background_image !== '' || $background_image !== ' ') ? " background-image:url('" . $_image[0] . "');" : "";
    $output .= '"';
    $output .= '>';
    $output .= $after_wrapper_open;
    if($parallax_content_width == "full_width"){
        $parallax_padding = "";
        if($parallax_side_padding != ""){
            $parallax_padding .= " style='padding: 0% ".$parallax_side_padding."%'";
        }
        $output .='<div class="parallax_content_full_width ' . $text_align . '" '. $parallax_padding .'>';
    }else{
        $output .='<div class="parallax_content ' . $text_align . '">';
    }
    $output .= "<div class='parallax_section_inner_margin clearfix'>";

}else if($row_type == 'expandable') {
    $output .= '<div '.$row_id.' '.$anchor_id.' '.$menu_title.' '.$menu_icon.' '.$header_style_data.' class="' . $css_class . $css_class_in_content_menu .'"';
    if($text_align != ""){
            $output .= " style='";
                $output .= ' text-align:' . $text_align . ';';
                $output.="'";
        }
    $output.=">";
    $output .= '<div class="more_facts_holder"';
    if($background_color != ""){
        $output .= " style='";
        if($background_color != ""){
            $output .= "background-color: ".$background_color.";";
        }
        $output .= "'";
    }
    $output .= '>';
    $output .= '<div class="more_facts_button_holder ' . $button_position . '">';
    $output .= '<span class="more_facts_button" data-color="'. $color . '" data-hovercolor="'. $hover_color . '" data-morefacts="'. $more_button_label .'" data-lessfacts="'. $less_button_label . '"';
    if($color != ""){
        $output .= " style='";
        if($color != ""){
            $output .= " color: ".$color.";";
        }
        $output .= "'";
    }
    $output .='><span class="more_facts_button_text">'. $more_button_label .'</span><span class="more_facts_button_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </span></span>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="more_facts_outer">';
    $output .= '<div class="more_facts_inner_holder"';
    $output .= '><div class="more_facts_inner" data-expandable_content_top_padding="'. $expandable_content_top_padding . '">';

} else if($row_type == 'content_menu'){
    $output .= '<nav '.$row_id.' class="content_menu"';
    if($background_color != ""){
        $output .= " style='background-color:".$background_color.";'";
    }
    $output .= '>';
    $output .= "<div class='nav_select_menu clearfix'><div class='nav_select_button'><i class='fa fa-bars'></i></div></div>";
}
if($row_type != 'content_menu'){
    $output .= wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content);
}
if($row_type == 'row') {
    if($css_animation != "") { 
        $output .= '</div></div>';
    }
        if($type == "grid"){
            $output .= "</div>";
        }
        $output .= '</div>';

    if($angled_section == 'yes' && $angled_section_position != 'top') {
        $output .= '<svg class="angled-section svg-bottom" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 86 86" width="100%" height="86">';
        if($angled_section_direction == 'from_left_to_right'){
            $output .= '<polygon points="0,0 86,0 86,86" ' . $angled_section_style . ' />';
        }
        if($angled_section_direction == 'from_right_to_left'){
            $output .= '<polygon points="0,0 0,86 86,0" ' . $angled_section_style . ' />';
        }
        $output .= '</svg>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>'.$this->endBlockComment('row');
}elseif($row_type == 'parallax'){
    $output .= '</div></div>';
    $output .= $before_wrapper_close;
    $output .= '</section>'.$this->endBlockComment('row');

}elseif($row_type == 'expandable'){
    $output .= '</div></div></div></div></div>'.$this->endBlockComment('row');
}else if($row_type == 'content_menu'){
    $output .= '</nav>';
}
echo $output;
```

Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a the solution. First of all I had to update the client's VC to an actual version and then use special plugin by WPbakery — that is the easiest way to solve this problem atm.